# Mock requests exception not being thrown by side_effect

Tags: python, exception, testing, mocking, python-requests

---

So I am trying to test exception handling code and side_effect is not working properly. The printed output shows that it is making the calls but the raise_for_status is not correctly throwing the exception in side_effect. Why is the exception not being thrown?

UPDATE: Okay, no idea why this works, but it does at least make it drop into the right except. I changed it to use patch.object and gave both the mock raise_for_status and mock get objects HTTPError() for side_effect. That got it to drop down into the correct except block but it still did not throw the exception according to the unit tests.

This is the code test_src.py located in test_package:

```
import requests
import sys
import traceback

def test_requests_function():
 try:
   response = requests.get('https://google.com/api/test', verify=False)
   response.raise_for_status()
   return response.json()
 except requests.exceptions.RequestException as error:
   return_message = "Exception: {0}".format(str(error))
   return {'return_code' : 500, 'message' : return_message, 'traceback' : traceback.format_exc()}
 except:
   return_message = "Unknown Exception: {0}".format(str(sys.exc_info()[0]))
   return {'return_code' : 500, 'message' : return_message, 'traceback' : traceback.format_exc()}
```

This is the test code:

```
import unittest
from pprint import pprint
import mock
import requests

from test_package import test_src

class TestRequestTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
  @mock.patch.object(requests, 'get')
  def test_request_exception(self, mock_get):
    http_error = requests.exceptions.HTTPError('Unable to connect')
    mock_raise_for_status = mock.Mock(side_effect=http_error)
    mock_get.raise_for_status = mock_raise_for_status
    mock_get.side_effect = http_error

    return_json = test_src.test_requests_function()
    print "\nMock_Get:"
    print id(mock_get)
    pprint(mock_get.__dict__)
    print "\nMock_Raise_For_Status:"
    print id(mock_raise_for_status)
    pprint(mock_raise_for_status.__dict__)
    print "\n"
    pprint(return_json)
```

So the ouptut is:

```
{'message': 'Exception: Unable to connect',
 'return_code': 500,
 'traceback': 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/Users/yshaban/test/test_package/test_src.py", line 8, in test_requests_function\n    response = requests.get(\'https://google.com/api/test\', verify=False)\n  File "/Users/yshaban/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1062, in __call__\n    return _mock_self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)\n  File "/Users/yshaban/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1118, in _mock_call\n    raise effect\nHTTPError: Unable to connect\n'
}

======================================================================

FAIL: test_request_exception (__main__.TestRequestTestCase)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yshaban/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1305, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "unit_tests.py", line 36, in test_request_exception
    pprint(return_json)
AssertionError: RequestException not raised

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I don't know how the test framework works, is `response` at mock test object?  If it is, are you sure IT doesn't handle the exceptions?  I noticed in the third output section that `_mock_side_effect` is `HTTPError()`.

Comment: Another thing I noticed... The output says that `requests.exceptions.HTTPError` is an unknown exception, so maybe that has something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are patching the wrong object. You should patch the `get` function in `test_src.requests`. Change (do not move) the decorator to:

```py
@mock.patch.object(test_src.requests, 'get')
```